# HTML output of whole page

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to generate html output of whole page and then pass it to response array.I am doing something like this:

```
  $page = array(
  '#theme' => 'html',
  '#page_object' => new HtmlPage(render($content)),
   );
```

`$content` is a render array and new HtmlPage creates a HtmlPage object from an existing page. I am passing `render($page)` to the response object, but I am getting error this error:

> LogicException: A stray `drupal_render()` invocation with `$is_root_call = TRUE` is causing bubbling of attached assets to break. in `Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender()` (line 377 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php).

What should I do to make this correct? Thanks

Comment: Try this: replace `'#page_object' => render($content),` with `'#page' => render($content),`

Comment: It would not change, since there is a direct call to `render()`.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. In order to give a more complete and useful answer, we need to see the complete code. The short answer is "never call `render()` or `drupal_render()`," but that is not much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`renderer` service](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/class/Renderer/8.4.x) instead as <del>`rendeer`</del> and <del>`drupal_render()`</del> is deprecated, e.g.

```
\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($content);
```

> Renders final HTML given a structured array tree.